# Update fail (libappindicator0.1-cil) Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

```
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor (int) <0x0001f>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCultureFromNeutral (string) <0x016c7>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture (string) <0x000e7>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.ConstructCurrentCulture () <0x00047>
  at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture () <0x0004b>
  at System.NumberFormatter..ctor (System.Threading.Thread) <0x0006b>
  at System.NumberFormatter.GetInstance () <0x0006b>
  at System.NumberFormatter.NumberToString (string,int,System.IFormatProvider) <0x0001b>
  at int.ToString (string,System.IFormatProvider) <0x00027>
  at string.FormatHelper (System.Text.StringBuilder,System.IFormatProvider,string,object[]) <0x00638>
  at string.Format (System.IFormatProvider,string,object[]) <0x00027>
  at string.Format (string,object) <0x00047>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor (int,bool,bool) <0x000f7>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor (int,bool) <0x00027>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor (int) <0x0001f>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCultureFromNeutral (string) <0x016c7>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture (string) <0x000e7>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.ConstructCurrentCulture () <0x00047>
  at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture () <0x0004b>
  at System.NumberFormatter..ctor (System.Threading.Thread) <0x0006b>
  at System.NumberFormatter.GetInstance () <0x0006b>
  at System.NumberFormatter.NumberToString (string,int,System.IFormatProvider) <0x0001b>
  at int.ToString (string,System.IFormatProvider) <0x00027>
  at string.FormatHelper (Sys
[4]+  Stopped                 sudo apt-get install libappindicator0.1-cil
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem on two laptops running Ubuntu 14.04.1 by doing the following:

- Start Synaptic.
- Search for "Mono", without quotes.
- Reinstall all packages already installed in the found list.
- Run in terminal: apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade

That's it!